# Загрузить n-нное кол-во постов в определенную категорию

Tags: sql, wordpress, wp-query

Есть сайт на вордпрессе. Можно ли одним запросом залить допустим 300 постов с категорией "new-post"? Интересует решение SQL-запросом. Спасибо.

Comment: Залить - это `INSERT`. 300 записей в ОДНУ таблицу одним запросом загрузить можно - но привязки-то? не в воздухе же у тебя эти посты повиснут...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Интересует решение SQL-запросом

Это в корне неправильное решение и по-нормальному не реализуется. Потому как во время создания постов создаются суррогатные ключи, которые записываются в другие таблицы.

Если же по каким-то религиозным причинам не устраивают готовые плагины, то правильное решение - сделать импорт через [API](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs). В частности [REST-API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).
А для непосредственно работы с базой есть [класс wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/ru:wpdb_Class)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Люто плюсую... )